# "As" keyword in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, as-keyword

Is there something similar to a `as` keyword in list comprehensions?

Example: instead of

```
L = [foo(bar(baz(bla(x)))) for x in X if foo(bar(baz(bla(x)))) == 1]
```

it would be:

```
L = [foo(bar(baz(bla(x)))) as y for x in X if y == 1]
```

Comment: If you are using 3.8 you can use the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Comment: `L = [1 for x in X if 1 == foo(bar(baz(bla(x)))) ]` would work in this case ... but walrussing is probably the better way

Comment: No, there isn't an `as` keyword, if you are on Python 3.8 you can use an assignment expression, i.e. the "walrus operator". If not, you can always just use the equivalent for-loop

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, (foo(...) for x in X)))`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Right, but this is because I took a trivial case where `foo(bar(baz(bla(x))))` is the same on both sides. If there is one less function on one side, `[1 for ...` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.8 you can use [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to do this:

```
>>> L = [y for x in X if (y := foo(bar(baz(bla(x))))) == 1]
```

Comment: why `y as y ` ?

Comment: Sorry, copied from OP's post, forgot to remove the `as`, corrected, thanks!